# No Access Control Allow origin error on 2 sub domains

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain

I'm trying to make an ajax get call between the two following sub domains:

```
Target URL: https://qa.mydomain.com
Origin URL: https://myotherqa.mydomain.com
```

I'm receiving the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://qa.mydomain.com/suggest?
q=foo. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
resource. Origin 'https://myotherqa.mydomain.com' is therefore not allowed 
access.
```

I'm using `$.get()` to make the ajax call

Both the websites are under the same sub domain and both 'https'.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: They could have different ports so that is fine. just enable the cors or use proxy at your server and then send a request the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is related to web security aka **Same origin policy**.

> Under the policy, a web browser permits scripts contained in a first
>   web page to access data in a second web page, but only if both web
>   pages have the same origin. An origin is defined as a combination of
>   URI scheme, hostname, and port number. - [More info here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

The proper solution to handle this is to allow CORS on your server side.
An alternative solution is using JSONP for get requests.

You can find some common settings and more information at this site:

http://enable-cors.org/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the server configuration the server is not accepting request from other domains for security concerns. Ports maybe different, enable the cors at the server level configuration. This will solve the issue.